# How to print text in Qt when a button is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, qprinter

I have been reading the Qt documentation for QPrinter and QPrintDialog but I cannot figure how to print the contents in a textEdit field.

Here is the code I have been try and which of course doesn't work.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>
#include <QPainter>


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString textFromField = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

    QPrinter printer;

    QPrintDialog *printDialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);

    printDialog->setWindowTitle("Print Document");

    if(printDialog->exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
    {

    }

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&printer);
    painter.drawText(100, 100, 500, 500,Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop, textFromField);
    painter.end();
}
```

This is the output I get when I run it.

> :-1: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Applications/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/qtbase/lib' :-1: error:
>   symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Again all I want is to print the contents in a textEdit field.

Comment: do you mean you just want to display a string variable in textEdit field?

Comment: No, I want to print on paper, using a printer.

Comment: maybe this can be helpful: http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt4/printing.html

Answer (score 1):

The QTextEdit is just an editor for a QTextDocument, which is a powerful class that knows how to print it's content.

```
QTextDocument *doc = ui->textEdit->document();
doc->print(&printer);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I'm probably doing something wrong because I'm getting errors. `void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Print_clicked() { QPrinter printer; QTextDocument *doc = ui->textEdit->document(); doc->print(&printer); }` **error** *C:\Users....\build-Printing-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\mainwindo‌​w.o:-1: In function ZN10MainWindow27on_pushButton_Print_clickedEv':*           **error**  *C:\Users\...\Printing\mainwindow.cpp:20: error: undefined reference to _imp___ZN8QPrinterC1ENS_11PrinterModeE'*

Comment: All errors that begin with "Undefined reference to ..." are linker errors. This means that your code has compiled correctly but something is failing in the final linking stage. Check that the libraries you're linking with were compiled with the same compiler you're using and that the Qt versions are compatible.

Comment: I had to add `QT       += printsupport` to the project file and it compiled without any errors, but now when I click the button I get the following output  **QPainter::begin(): Returned false** Any idea why?